# pyqt4 emiting signals in threads to slots in main thread

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, signals-slots

I have some custom signals in my main thread that I would like to emit in my other threads but I'm not sure how to connect them. Could someone post an example?

ex:

```
import sys, time
from PyQt4 import QtGui as qt
from PyQt4 import QtCore as qtcore

app = qt.QApplication(sys.argv)
class widget(qt.QWidget):
    signal = qtcore.pyqtSignal(str)
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        qt.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.signal.connect(self.testfunc)

    def appinit(self):
        thread = worker()
        thread.start()

    def testfunc(self, sigstr):
        print sigstr

class worker(qtcore.QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        qtcore.QThread.__init__(self, parent=app)

    def run(self):
        time.sleep(5)
        print "in thread"
        self.emit(qtcore.SIGNAL("signal"),"hi from thread")

def main():
    w = widget()
    w.show()
    qtcore.QTimer.singleShot(0, w.appinit)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

main()
```

signal never raised.

Comment: I forgot to mention they are new style signals

Comment: Do you use QThread or python's thread ?

Comment: Can you post a non-working example, because signals and slots are supposed to work across QThread by default and no special treatment is needed

Comment: A bit too simple. Can you modify it so I can just copy and run :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You actually connect the wrong signal to the slot. Some modification make it run as expected

```
import sys, time
from PyQt4 import QtGui as qt
from PyQt4 import QtCore as qtcore

app = qt.QApplication(sys.argv)
class widget(qt.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        qt.QWidget.__init__(self)

    def appinit(self):
        thread = worker()
        self.connect(thread, thread.signal, self.testfunc)
        thread.start()

    def testfunc(self, sigstr):
        print sigstr

class worker(qtcore.QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        qtcore.QThread.__init__(self, parent=app)
        self.signal = qtcore.SIGNAL("signal")
    def run(self):
        time.sleep(5)
        print "in thread"
        self.emit(self.signal, "hi from thread")

def main():
    w = widget()
    w.show()
    qtcore.QTimer.singleShot(0, w.appinit)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

main()
```

Comment: PyQT Docs say: "The parent argument, if not None, causes self to be owned by Qt instead of PyQt." How does qtcore.QThread.__init__(self, parent=app) work here? Where does the app argument comes from?

Comment: app is define in line 5. As for why `qtcore.QThread.__init__(self, parent=app)` was used, I have no idea. I just copied it from the original code.

Comment: I ran that code, but I have a problem. The widget showed was frezzing while during the def testfunc.

Comment: If it's freezing than it means that it's not running in a separate thread but in the main one where the GUI is residing.