# PyQT4: get values from another python module in parallel thread

Tags: python, module, pyqt4, python-multithreading, qthread

Got some problem with PyQT and QThread.
When using method from another module in QThread run(), i can't get values from it.
How can i get them?

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys


class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):

    QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
    self.initAnotherThread()
    self.setFixedSize(640, 360)
    self.setWindowTitle('Window')

    self.logText = QtGui.QTextEdit(self)
    self.logText.setReadOnly(True)
    self.logText.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
    self.logText.resize(460, 330)

    self.clickButton = QtGui.QPushButton('Click Button', self)
    self.clickButton.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
    self.clickButton.setGeometry(470, 50, 160, 35)
    self.connect(self.clickButton, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.onButtonClick)

def initAnotherThread(self):
    self.updaterThread = anotherThread(self)

def onButtonClick(self):
    self.logText.clear()
    self.updaterThread.start()

class anotherThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, mw):
        super(anotherThread, self).__init__(mw)
        self.mw = mw

    def run(self):
        print "Another thread started"
        AnotherModule.anotherMethod()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In AnotherModule i have next:

```
anotherMethod():
    x=0
    while x<100:
        x+=1
```

What should i do to get x value from AnotherModule?

Comment: You want to get x while its iterating or after?

Comment: While its iterating.

Comment: This answer seems to cover that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9618169/1470749