# PyQt5 - How to emit signal from worker tread to call event by GUI thread

Tags: python, pyqt5

As I Mentioned in Title. How can i do something like this?

```
class Main(QWidget):

        def __init__(self):

                super().__init__()

        def StartButtonEvent(self):

                self.test = ExecuteThread()
                self.test.start()

        def MyEvent(self):

                #MainThreadGUI

class ExecuteThread(QThread):

        def run(self):

                # A lot of work

                # Signal to main thread about finishing of job = mainthread will perform MyEvent
```

I found some tutorials here [pyqt4 emiting signals in threads to slots in main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9614947/pyqt4-emiting-signals-in-threads-to-slots-in-main-thread)

and here [Emit signal from pyQt Qthread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37081098/emit-signal-from-pyqt-qthread-causes-python-exe-crash)

But it seems it does not working in PyQt5 :/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use the [QThread.finished](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#finished) signal here. It will be executed automatically if you finish your thread.
Of course you can also define your own custom signal if you want.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal

class Main(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def StartButtonEvent(self):
        self.test = ExecuteThread()
        self.test.start()
        self.test.finished.connect(thread_finished)
        self.test.my_signal.connect(my_event)

    def thread_finished(self):
        # gets executed if thread finished
        pass

    def my_event(self):
        # gets executed on my_signal 
        pass


class ExecuteThread(QThread):
    my_signal = pyqtSignal()

    def run(self):
        # do something here
        self.my_signal.emit()
        pass
```

Comment: That was so simple! :) Thanks you very much!

Comment: Can i have one more question? Can i add some argument into this signals? Or is there any other easy procedure how to achieve it? For example send some int or string in argument

Comment: Yes, adding arguments is easy. Just have a look at the official PyQt5 documentation for [Signals and Slots](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html)

Comment: In the start `StartButtonEvent` function, shouldn't the slots be referenced as `self.thread_finished` and `self.my_event`. Although every function can be used as a slot, it would be a good idea to use the `@pyqtSlot()` decorator. And even it it may only be for the sake of self explaining code.

Comment: thread_finished and my_event are never trigger with my computer from the ExecuteThread. But my_event can be triggered if self.my_signal.emit() is run from the Main class. Any idea ???