# Checking the status of a python thread from a seperate function

Tags: python, multithreading

Currently I am able to run a thread and update label items in a GUI (pyqt5) as the thread is running. However, I want to add information on the status of the thread, i.e. when the thread starts (label updated as :'thread initiated') and when the thread ends (label updated as: 'thread complete'). The thread start update is not a problem because I can update the label as soon as the thread is initiated. However, the thread end update is somewhat more problematic since I have no way of knowing when the thread has finished. I have tried thread.join(), though this prevents dynamic update of labels when the thread is running (The GUI freezes until the thread has finished). I have tried to update the label from a separate function but with no success.

My current code (shortened):

```
def onbuttonpress(self):
    self.label.setText('thread initiated')
    self.simulation() 
    self.label.setText('thread finished')

def simulation(self):
        def sim():
            pythoncom.CoInitialize()


        ------code-----

        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=mt)
        self.thread.start()
```

Is there a alternative to thread.join() that works without crashing GUIs?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the timeout parameter of `join()` to try joining, if unsuccessful, it's not ready yet.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join

For the duration of the timeout, the GUI thread will be blocked, so set it to a small value (e.g. 1 ms). Do this check periodically (e.g. once every second) until the thread is done.

Alternatively, use the signal-slot mechanism of Qt to notify the GUI thread from the worker thread.

[pyqt4 emiting signals in threads to slots in main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9614947/pyqt4-emiting-signals-in-threads-to-slots-in-main-thread)

[PyQt5 - How to emit signal from worker tread to call event by GUI thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41184719/pyqt5-how-to-emit-signal-from-worker-tread-to-call-event-by-gui-thread?noredirect=1&lq=1)