# Thread issue in Qt (Gui)

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qthread

I am working on an application to download files from the internet.
I have used Qt for this purpose.
The download process is run in a separate thread using a QThread object which contains a while loop.
To show the progress I have a label inside main thread and to update that I send signal to the main thread.
**The problem is the label shows value 0 when the download thread starts and remains 0, and after the download finishes it suddenly shows 100.**
There are no in between values.
How can I fix this issue?

I have already used `repaint()` , `processEvents()` and `update` methods. They don't work.

Here is some of the code for reference:

This is class thread for creating threads for download.

```
class signal(QObject):       #For creating signals
sgn=pyqtSignal()
ma=pyqtSignal()
jo=pyqtSignal()
def __init__(self):
    super(signal,self).__init__()

class thread(QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(thread,self).__init__()
        self.w=signal()
    def run(self):
        global url
        global video
        global val
        self.w.ma.emit()
        size=url.get_filesize()
        f=open(video.title+'.'+url.extension,"wb")
        resp=urllib.request.urlopen(url.url)
        l=0
        print(size)
        while True:
            buf=resp.read(65536)
            if not buf:
                f.close()
                return
            l+=len(buf)
            val=l//size*100     # val is global variable for progress value
            self.w.sgn.emit()   # Here I emit the signal
            f.write(buf)
```

The thread object and the label is defined in the main GUI thread.

After the user presses the download button, I start the thread.

```
#Main thread
.
.
self.obj=thread()
self.obj.w.sgn.connect(self.m)
def m(self):     #Slot for updating
    global val
    print("Here")   #For checking
    self.label.setText(str(val))
```

P.S. - "Here" gets printed in the console repeatedly and stops after download is complete.

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: It is a very large chunk of code.

Comment: Just include the relevant code (see [mcve]). How do you emit the download state? Have you checked if intermediate progress is effectively emitted?

Comment: Yes. I have checked that intermediate progress is transmitted by printing some message on the console.So that is not an issue!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9614947/pyqt4-emiting-signals-in-threads-to-slots-in-main-thread

Comment: I don't think that is a problrm zeFrenchy. This is because "Here" gets printed in the console repeatedly. Please see the code.

Comment: @user8140261. Every time you use global variables like that, a puppy will die. So just don't ever do that. Define the signal like this: `sgn = pyqtSignal(int)`. Then send the value like this: `self.w.sgn.emit(val)`. The slot connected to this signal will then need to define a parameter to receive the emitted value.

Comment: Please edit the question to properly indent the code, considering this is Python where whitespace matters.

Comment: @ekhumoro. Yeah but it didn't work.